# How to set and get values from an other file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS I want to create a file in which I want to create `set` and `get` method  for setting and then getting some value. I have created a file `myAppModel` (posted below) but I don't exactly know how to set and get values from this file in my controller file. So can someone please guide how can I set and get `channel_list` variable in `myAppModel` file from my controller file?

**myAppModel.js**

```
var channel_list;

function set_channel_list(channels) {
    channel_list = channels;
}

function get_channel_list() {
    return channel_list;
}
```

**myCtrl.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use a service https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include your files in the HTML

```
/// myCtrl.js
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="myAppModel.js"></script>
<body>
...

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        get_channel_list(); 
    });
</script>
```

Now you can use *set_channel_list* and *get_channel_list* in myCtrl.js. You could create an angular service like others have suggested, but it alone will not achieve what you want.

As your application grows you will want to look into a bundler and tools like Webpack, Gulp or Rollup. Then you could for example (using ES6 imports) do this:

**myAppModel.js**

```
var channel_list;

export function get_channel_list() { ... }
```

**myCtrl.js**

```
import { get_channel_list } from 'myAppModel';

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    get_channel_list();
});
```

A bundler would build a file that (eg. *main.js*) you could then include in the template.

**main.html**

```
...
<script src="main.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: but how can I call get_channel_list(); in another js file instead of calling it in html file

Comment: Not possible without a javascript bundler. What they do I join all your files into a single one, so the code runs correctly. I suggest looking into [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service for this. And you can have this service in a different file.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, channelService) {
  $scope.test = channelService.getMyChannel();
});

app.service('channelService', function() {
    this.channel_list = [];

    this.set_channel_list = function(channels) {
        this.channel_list = channels;
    };
    
    this.get_channel_list = function() {
        return this.channel_list;
    };

    this.getMyChannel= function() {
      return 'ABC';
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{test}}
</div>
```

Learn more about the services in Angularjs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: but how can I call get_channel_list(); in another js file instead of calling it in html file